# PHP array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm trying to access a php array. But it is throwing me Array to string conversion error.

This is my code

```
if(isset($_POST['category'])){
               $category = array($_POST['category']);
                if(sizeof($category) > 0){
                    foreach($category as $key){
                       $categ = $categ.$key.', ';
                   }   
               }
           }
```

Comment: what is contained in $_POST['category']? a string or an array?

Comment: `print_r()` your variables - one of them that you think is a string (`$categ`, `$key`) is not a string. also initialize your variables - your next problem will be `$categ is undefined` (the first time you access it).

Comment: In this case category must be array of objects. $key itself should be an object which can't be converted to string.

Comment: Get rid of the array in `$category = array($_POST['category']);`. You're probably getting an array already in `$_POST['category'];`.

Comment: I think you meant  `$category = (array)$_POST['category'];` ;)

Comment: Side note: `sizeof($category)` is 1. Always. You create a one item array in the previous line.

Comment: @OneTrickPony: `(array)$_POST['category']` is equivalent to `array($_POST['category'])` *if* `$_POST['category']` is a scalar value.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Not at all, one is type casting as an array, the other is creating an array with one key containing another array

Comment: @AD7six: I said **if it's a scalar value** http://ideone.com/Q8hktW

Comment: @happyaccidents: I said **If it's a scalar value** http://ideone.com/Q8hktW

Comment: @AD7six: Ok, ok.  You win.  I am defeated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this..

```
if (isset($_POST['category'])) {

    if (!is_array($_POST['category'])) {
        $category = array($_POST['category']);
    } else {
        $category = $_POST['category'];
    }

    $categ = '';

    foreach ($category as $value) {
        if (!is_string($value)) {
            // do anything, but not autocast to string!
            continue;
        }
        $categ .= $value . ', ';
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job.

```
if (is_array($_POST['category'])) {

    $category = implode(", ", $_POST['category']);

}
```